# Tensorflow: feeding data to the graph

Tags: tensorflow

I have written an algorithm using Tensorflow. The structure of my code is as follows:

1. Read data from a csv and store it in a list of lists, where each list contains a single line from a csv.
2. Use the `feed_dict` approach to feed the graph a single line of data. This is done in a loop till all the lines are processed.

The TF graph is executed on the GPU. My question is related to the data transfer which will happen from the CPU to the GPU. Does using `feed_dict` mean that there will be lots of small transfers from the host to the device? If yes, would it be feasible to do a bulk transfer using `feed_dict` and use a loop in the TF graph?

Comment: It's possible that these small transfers are not a bottleneck, so improving the transfer speed won't improve your training throughput much. So you should profile things before optimizing. If it's indeed the bottleneck, it's possible to prefetch things to GPU in parallel with training, for instance using Tim Zaman's approach [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722#issuecomment-266297116)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to profile this? I tried using nvprof to obtain some metrics, but it did not give me anything when used with Tensorflow code. nvprof works when I use it with raw CUDA code.

Comment: Instead of using `feed_dict` directly, store `batch` in TensorFlow variable pinned to GPU. In one `session.run` run `tf.assign` and `feed_dict` to feed batch into that variable. In second `session.run`, do the actual computation that takes batch from the variable instead of placeholder. Then if you comment out the first session run, you'll get the maximum speed attainable with prefetching solution

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the file size is small (e.g. single line of text) there will likely be many small host to device transfers.

Here is an example of using feed_dict with a custom fill_feed_dict function: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py

For your use though, it may be easier to handle many small files using TensorFlow's QueueRunner.  This will create a pool of reader threads to prefetch your data and help speed up data availability to the TensorFlow graph.

```
 Create the graph, etc.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize the variables (like the epoch counter).
sess.run(init_op)

# Start input enqueue threads.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        # Run training steps or whatever
        sess.run(train_op)

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

(https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/#batching)